# Google Calendar API v3 quickAdd fail

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

First, I can add the event from Google API web page
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/quickAdd#try-it successfully by input "calendarId" and "text" parameters

But I am failed to use "quickAdd" API to add event in Google calendar by using PHP.

```
require_once "google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php";
require_once "google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/Calendar.php";

// Service Account info
$calName = 'dcm2p5gkf3ge1r7k78f0ko28tc@group.calendar.google.com';
$client_id = '759399732845-j93sis8dktkdj00l3b8mn7gjs3ncf6b9.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$service_account_name = '759399732845-j93sis8dktkdj00l3b8mn7gjs3ncf6b9@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$key_file_location = 'SMSProject-f14380ee82e4.p12';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("SMSProject");

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials($service_account_name, array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'), $key);

$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
$createdEvent = $service->events->quickAdd('primary', 'Appointment at Somewhere on January 23rd 10am-10:25am');
echo $createdEvent->getId();
```

Event ID "g69tq9k7s38rfgit1mpnit9bpk" can be echo in the browser but no event is shown in the calendar

If I change

```
$createdEvent = $service->events->quickAdd('primary', 'Appointment at Somewhere on January 23rd 10am-10:25am');
```

to

```
$createdEvent = $service->events->quickAdd($calName, 'Appointment at Somewhere on January 23rd 10am-10:25am');
```

Event ID cannot be generated and show below error message

> Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/dcm2p5gkf3ge1r7k78f0ko28tc%40group.calendar.google.com/events/quickAdd: (404) Not Found

I need to use "quickAdd" instead of "insert" API. How to solve the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, but then I discovered that it was, in fact, creating the events in the calendar for the Service Account xxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com instead of my personal calendar.
If you want it to create the events in your personal calendar that you use, go into the settings for your personal calendar and share it with your Service Account xxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com
then you should be able to use...

```
$createdEvent = $service->events->quickAdd($calName, 'Appointment at Somewhere on January 23rd 10am-10:25am');
```

...instead of 'primary'